# Getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException when trying to import data with Liquibase, but can insert it from MySQL CLI or Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, liquibase

I need some help. I'm using Liquibase im my project and after creation of tables trying to import data, but getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException.

This line in my import.sql

> INSERT INTO visitors(id, name, password, email, created) VALUES(1,
>   'user', 'password', 'valid@mail', '1945-09-09 05:55:00');

generates this exception:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO visitors(id, name, password, email, created)
>   VALUES(1, 'user', 'password', 'valid@mail', '1945-09-09 05:55:00');'

But when I execute it from MySQL CLI - data is successfully inserted. Have no idea where to look for. Could you, please, give some suggestions where to look for root cause?

Comment: can you put more code please?

Comment: When syntax errors say there's a problem "near" the statement, it means it didn't expect the part that it shows in the error. For example, if you had a statement before the INSERT, but failed to terminate the preceding statement with a semicolon.